# how to save multi level dict per line?

Tags: python, json

i have this dict

```
dd = {
    "A": {"a": {"1": "b", "2": "f"}, "z": ["z", "q"]},
    "B": {"b": {"1": "c", "2": "g"}, "z": ["x", "p"]},
    "C": {"c": {"1": "d", "2": "h"}, "z": ["y", "o"]},
     }
```

and i wanna have it formated in one line like this in a file i used

```
with open('file.json', 'w') as file: json.dump(dd, file, indent=1)
# result
{
 "A": {
  "a": {
   "1": "b",
   "2": "f"
  },
  "z": [
   "z",
   "q"
  ]
 },
 "B": {
  "b": {
   "1": "c",
   "2": "g"
  },
  "z": [
   "x",
   "p"
  ]
 },
 "C": {
  "c": {
   "1": "d",
   "2": "h"
  },
  "z": [
   "y",
   "o"
  ]
 }
}
```

i also tried but gave me string and list wrong

```
with open('file.json', 'w') as file: file.write('{\n' +',\n'.join(json.dumps(f"{i}: {dd[i]}") for i in dd) +'\n}')
# result
{
"A: {'a': {'1': 'b', '2': 'f'}, 'z': ['z', 'q']}",
"B: {'b': {'1': 'c', '2': 'g'}, 'z': ['x', 'p']}",
"C: {'c': {'1': 'd', '2': 'h'}, 'z': ['y', 'o']}"
}
```

the result i wanna is

```
    {
    "A": {"a": {"1": "b", "2": "f"}, "z": ["z", "q"]},
    "B": {"b": {"1": "c", "2": "g"}, "z": ["x", "p"]},
    "C": {"c": {"1": "d", "2": "h"}, "z": ["y", "o"]},
     }
```

how do i print the json content one line per dict while all inside is one line too?

i plan to read it using `json.load`

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON requires double quotes around all strings, you can't use single quotes.

Comment: JSON formatters are not really intended to be customizable to this degree. They offer the option to spread over multiple lines with indentation to make it readable, but you don't get any finer control.

Comment: @Barmar how does tools like scrapy do it?

Comment: I have no idea, I've never used it. They may have written their own JSON implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stdlib [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module does not really support that, but you should be able to write a function which does similar pretty easily. Something like:

```
import json

def my_dumps(dd):
    lines = []
    for k, v in dd.items():
        lines.append(json.dumps({k: v})[1:-1])
    return "{\n" + ",\n".join(lines) + "\n}"
```

If all you wanted was to wrap json to some more human-friendly line width, without totally spacing out everything like using `indent` option does, then another option might be using [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap):

```
>>> print("\n".join(textwrap.wrap(json.dumps(dd), 51)))
{"A": {"a": {"1": "b", "2": "f"}, "z": ["z", "q"]},
"B": {"b": {"1": "c", "2": "g"}, "z": ["x", "p"]},
"C": {"c": {"1": "d", "2": "h"}, "z": ["y", "o"]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['{\n']
for i in dd :
    x.append('"'+i+'": '+str(dd[i]).replace("'",'"')+",\n")       
x[-1] = x[-1][:-2]
x.append("\n}")
with open('file.json', 'w') as file: 
    file.writelines(x)
```

Image of the output :-

[image]

Comment: What if some of the keys have " characters sin them?  What if some of the values have ' characters in them?